# Where is Linux CFS Scheduler Code?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduler

I have complete linux source code for version 3.13. I was trying to find out source code for CFS scheduler which according to popular books should reside inside /kernel/sched.c for base scheduler code and /kernel/sched_fair.c specifically for CFS code. I just made a code wide global search for those two files inside my 3.13 linux code which turned up no results. I also individually searched /linux-3.13/kernel folder and /linux-3.13/kernel/sched folders. Still no luck.

I wanted someone to shed light on where CFS is located inside the new linux kernel code domain(linux-3.13.*). Please excuse me if I am missing something here. I am a beginner to linux kernel.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Source code changes quickly and books are updated slowly. Its in [kernel/sched/fair.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/sched/fair.c).

Answer (score 4):

All the scheduler code is now in the `kernel/sched/` directory.

Answer (score 2):

CFS scheduler code is in kernel/sched_fair.c
(Kernel 3.0.4)