# User Thread to Kernel Thread mapping in Linux systems

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, operating-system

I understand how the User Thread to Kernel Thread mapping takes place. What I dont understand is how this is implemented in present day Real Time Linux Kernels. Do we still have the process where the User Thread will make a system call and then sleep while the Kernel Thread will manage the system call and then return? Or does the kernel increase the privilege mode of the User Thread and give it the privileges of the Kernel Thread and there by allowing it to perform the system call that it called for in the first place.

Also a follow up question is that do we have 2 schedulers? A scheduler for the User Space Threads and a scheduler for Kernel Space Threads?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371735/where-is-linux-cfs-scheduler-code

Comment: The first sentence is wrong; there is no mapping.

Comment: Plenty of text books and links mention the existence of a "mapping". Below is a link from Wikipedia:
[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29#Models)

Comment: It is probably different from what you have in mind, the link refers to the implementation of multithreading whether it be in user space only where multiple "user threads" are scheduled in the same "kernel thread" or a 1:1 mapping between a user thread and a kernel thread.

Comment: Real time Linux kernels are standard Linux kernel modified to get better and more deterministic response time to interrupts mainly. The scheduling of user threads is unchanged.